how to make jupyter lab prepared by matplotlib interactive?
I am using this code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle  # Import for rectangle visualization


def load_data(file_path):
    """
    Loads data from a text file into a NumPy array.

    Args:
        file_path (str): Path to the text file.

    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: A NumPy array containing the data, or None if an error occurs.
    """
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            data = [line.strip().split(';') for line in lines if line.strip()]
            data = np.array(data, dtype=float)
        return data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File not found: {file_path}")
        return None

def plot_correlated_maps(map1, map2, name1='Fe', name2='Al', title='Iron vs Aluminum Correlation'):
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 10))

  # Plot Fe map
  fe_map = axs[0, 0].imshow(map1, cmap='viridis')
  axs[0, 0].set_title('Fe Map')

  # Plot Al map
  al_map = axs[0, 1].imshow(map2, cmap='plasma')
  axs[0, 1].set_title('Al Map')

  # Plot Merged map
  combined_image = 0.5 * map1 + 0.5 * map2
  merged_map = axs[1, 0].imshow(combined_image, cmap='magma')
  axs[1, 0].set_title('Merged Map')

  # Scatter plot
  scatter_plot = axs[1, 1].scatter(map1.flatten(), map2.flatten(), alpha=0.5)
  axs[1, 1].set_xlabel(name1)
  axs[1, 1].set_ylabel(name2)
  axs[1, 1].set_title(title)

  roi = None  # Initialize ROI as None

  def update_plots(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    if roi is not None:
      roi.set_visible(False)  # Hide previous ROI

    roi_map1 = map1[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    roi_map2 = map2[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    fe_map.set_data(roi_map1)
    al_map.set_data(roi_map2)
    combined_roi = 0.5 * roi_map1 + 0.5 * roi_map2
    merged_map.set_data(combined_roi)

    scatter_plot.set_offsets(np.column_stack((roi_map1.flatten(), roi_map2.flatten())))

    # Create a new rectangle for ROI visualization
    roi = Rectangle(xy=(x1, y1),
                     lw=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none',
                     width=x2 - x1, height=y2 - y1)
    axs[0, 0].add_patch(roi)
    axs[0, 1].add_patch(roi)
    axs[1, 0].add_patch(roi)

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

  def onselect(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = int(eclick.xdata), int(eclick.ydata)
    x2, y2 = int(erelease.xdata), int(erelease.ydata)
    update_plots(x1, y1, x2, y2)

  rect_selector = RectangleSelector(axs[0, 0], onselect, useblit=True,
                                     button=[1], minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                     spancoords='pixels', interactive=True)

  plt.tight_layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Replace with actual file paths for Fe and Al maps
  map1_file = 'Fe.txt'
  map2_file = 'Al.txt'

  # Read data from text files
  map1 = load_data(map1_file)
  map2 = load_data(map2_file)

  if map1 is None or map2 is None:
      print("Error: Unable to load map data.")
  else:
      plot_correlated_maps(map1, map2, name1='Fe', name2='Al', title='Iron vs Aluminum Correlation')
  


and the output of the given code is
output
I want one modification, when i draw a roi in any of the Map, all map should zoomed for that ROI and correspondingly correlation plot should vary.
The map file are attached in drive link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bMlBfi5TuyoIIVSQCxF8P3lgEPc58ljC?usp=drive_link
I have tried to make ROI but it is not working. I want when I zoom any of the map all should zoom and make correlation plot accordingly. also need help which GUI i should use to run as required.

One tool to help with region of interests & selections is mpl-interactions, see here. However, that is in general & you need subplots, too. It may well work with subplots as here seems to suggest. The most mature thing I see related to what you are asking is here, as covered in the comments to 'Matplotlib/Pyplot: How to zoom subplots together?'.

 Depending on how you implement this, I assume you are using current JupyterLab and so you will likely need to install ipympl and set your plots to use it, see here to get started.
